# chef - using recipes from same cookbook

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I have cookbook `base` and cookbook `myapp`

base has 2 recipes - `my_java` and `java_with_custom_stuff`

in `java_with_custom_stuff` I want to use the recipe for `my_java` (same cookbook). something like

```
include_recipe 'my_java'

bash 'custom stuff' do
...
end
```

in `myapp` I do
`include_recipe "base::java_with_custom_stuff"`

yet it complains that it cannot find `my_java`

Is there a way to use a recipe from the same cookbook?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`include_recipe` uses the first part every time as the cookbook name. So you have to specify the cookbook - name + recipe name:

```
include_recipe '::my_java' # works still after you rename your cookbook
include_recipe 'base::my_java' # works only as long as your cookbook name is base
```